# How can I use a Math method to style an element?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to give the element a random width of 1 - 100% but this isn't working.

```
  document.querySelector(".box").style.width = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)%;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate `%` as a string:

```js
document.querySelector(".box").style.width = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + '%';
```